# How to create a flexible table-like layout?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a layout that looks like a table, but where the number of columns can change fluidly, depending on the width of the browser window.

Currently, I am using the `flexbox` display to simulate the effect of fluid columns, but I have no idea how to make the width of flex items consistent between the rows. Here is the sample HTML code:

```
<a>image</a>
<ul>
    <li>dsdfsdfd dsfdf sdfsdf sdfsd</li>
    <li><span>sdfsdds</span><span>sdfsdds</span></li>
    <li><span>sdfsdd dgdfgfgd dg dfdfs</span><span>sdfsdds</span><span>sdfsdds</span></li>
    <li>dsdfsdfd dsfdf sdfsdf sdfsd</li>
    <li><span>sdfsdg fg fg ds</span><span>sdfsdds</span></li>
    <li>dsdfsdfd dsfdf sdfsdf sdfsd</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the sample CSS:

```
a {
    float: right;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background: cyan;
}
ul {
    padding: 0px;
}
li {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

li span {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-width: 50px;
}
```

Please refer to this [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e6wC2/1/) for a better idea of what I am trying to achieve. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is your content tabular data or not? And what do you mean by "change fluidly": hide it or wrap it to a new row?

Comment: @Jeroen, the content is something like a profile with personal data, of which some are related and can be displayed on the same row. Fluid here means to wrap to a new row.